# Sending UDP RAW Data on windows with python

Tags: python, sockets, udp, ethernet

I want to sending simple data with UDP protocol, I have tested on ubuntu and it worked, here's my code

```
import time
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
s.bind(("eno2", 0))

ethernet  = b'\x7c\x10\xc9\x51\xb7\x7b' # MAC Address Destination
ethernet += b'\x7c\x10\xc9\x51\xb3\xd6' # MAC Address Source
ethernet += b'\x08\x00'                 # Protocol-Type: IPv4

ip_header  = b'\x45\x00\x00\x2a'  # Version, IHL, Type of Service | Total Length
ip_header += b'\xa0\x6a\x00\x00'  # Identification | Flags, Fragment Offset
ip_header += b'\x80\x11\x0e\xe5'  # TTL, Protocol | Header Checksum
ip_header += b'\xc0\xa8\x05\x0f'  # Source Address
ip_header += b'\xc0\xa8\x05\x14'  # Destination Address

udp_header  = b'\xce\x55\xc3\x55' # Source Port | Destination Port
udp_header += b'\x00\x16\x1f\x83' # Sequence Number

data  = b'\x68\x65\x6c\x6c'
data += b'\x6f\x20\x77\x6f'
data += b'\x72\x6c\x64\x20'
data += b'\x31\x31'

padding  = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
packet = ethernet + ip_header + udp_header + data
while True:
    s.send(packet)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

but when I running on windows AF_PACKET has no attribute on Socket module, so what similar AF_PACKET on windows? someone can help me?

I just want to send UDP RAW Data on windows

Comment: `AF_PACKET` doesn't exist on Windows, and there is no equivalent. You simply can't access the Ethernet layer using RAW sockets on Windows. You have to use 3rd party libraries, such as winpcap/npcap, which have access to the whole networking system. Why do you need this, exactly? You don't need to resort to RAW access just to send UDP data. So what exactly are you trying to accomplish that a standard UDP socket can't handle on its own?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the information, actually i want to send data with a specific mac address, do you have a reference for me?